# Cryptocode package question, protocol with 4 players

Tags: pdftex, diagrams, tikz-graphdrawing

I am using cryptocode package to make a protocol of 4 players.

```
\fbox{
\procedure{name}{%
 \textbf{Alice}  \< \textbf{Verisign}  \< \textbf{Eve}  \< \textbf{Bob} \\
\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
\<\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
\<\<\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
 }
 }
```

My issues is the following: 
1) how to create long arrow from Alice to Eve for example. (and arrow back)
2) how to keep the diagram size within the page size
[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Does `texdoc cryptocode` help you?  If not you might try emailing the author directly.

Comment: @samcarter I do not see that this is a duplicate. The two specific questions here are not addressed in the other questions at all.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, because the other one was about drawing the diagram. This question is related to the length of the arrows. I have managed to solve it. I would like to add my answer if reopened.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\sendmessageleftx` and `\sendmessagerightx` commands to create arrows that bypass one or more parties. Currently these do not compute the correct length on their own, so you would need to play a bit with the size parameter. 
The commands take an optional length parameter, the number of columns to bypass and the text to show on top of the arrow.

```
\fbox{
\procedure{name}{
 \textbf{Alice}  \<\< \textbf{Verisign}  \<\< \textbf{Eve}  \<\< \textbf{Bob} \\
 \<\sendmessageright{length=2cm,top=\text{hello}} \\
 \<\<\<\sendmessageright{length=2cm,top=\text{hello}} \\
 \<\<\<\<\<\sendmessageright{length=2cm,top=\text{hello}} \\
 \<\sendmessageleftx[8cm]{12}{\text{hello back to Alice}}\<  \\
}}
```

This produces the following protocol

[image: Multiparty protocol]

Note that I've introduced columns for the messages. Thus the final message from Bob back to Alice goes over 6 `\<` each creating two columns and thus 12 columns in total.